# MySQL - search in longtext

Tags: mysql, sql

I believe this question will be useful for many MySQL newbies like me. Are there any means to search through the LONGTEXT type? As I see, FULLTEXT can be used only for TEXT fields, which doesn't suit me, because of size.

P.S. I heard around, that LONGTEXT is stored as a BLOB, and therefore can't be searched with standard methods. But are there any workarounds?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: work arounds? work around what, exactly?

Comment: If I got correclty, LONGTEXT cant be searched with standard methods. But, for example, in Wordpress, where post content is a LONGTEXT, there is a search that searches through the content. So, there **must** be a workaround.

Comment: I have a thought to split up the LONGTEXT into multiple columns. I was working with the wordpress posts.post_content which has embedded html like tags in it. Don't have a full solution yet, but found that I can copy it into multiple SUBSTRINGS 65535 in size each. `SELECT SUBSTRING(post_content,1,65535) post_content1, SUBSTRING(post_content,65536,65535) post_content2, SUBSTRING(post_content,131071,65535) post_content3
FROM wp_posts Pst 
WHERE pst.post_type = 'post' AND 
AND LENGTH(Pst.post_content) > 150000` -- Now that works in splitting up a LONGTEXT field into 3 65535 fields. Works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, FULLTEXT doesn't work with LONGTEXT column types, according to the [documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

You can implement your own searching through the LIKE functionality:

```
select postid,content from POSTS where content like '%keyword%';
```

but this will be nowhere as efficient as using FULLTEXT searching.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using a concatenation of data stored in a FullText, and an ID stored in another field.

If you require the data to be seperated into fields you can use another table with seperated fields joined with the first table by ID. This way you can use both LongText (in the table with seperate fields), and fulltext in the search table.

Comment: Well, that thought crossed my mind, too, I'll try it out some day. Now, I guess, I can sacrifice some speed for simplicity.

Comment: it all depends on the quantity of records of course. A few hundred thousand and you might notice a bit of a lag, several million and you need another solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

In documentation they have specified only for CHAR,VARCHAR,TEXT columns Full text search is supported. They have specified TEXT in general which includes TINYTEXT,TEXT,LONGTEXT,MEDIUMTEXT