# Number of occurences for a set of terms in a range of cells

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which in a column are stored entries consisting of long strings (rich text, in fact HTML). From there, some 1000 cells (by one in a row) are of my interest. 
Now I have a pre-defined list of ~100 terms and I need to check:

1. how many occurences are in these 1000 cells for each of these 100 terms, and
2. how many terms of these 100 occurs in each of these 1000 cells

Could someone help me with such queries? I hope they will not timeout, as the table is quite large (656k rows/135 MB). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the structure of your table? (We need the CREATE TABLE command.) Also, what is the delimiter of your terms within the HTML? (<TD>...</TD>, etc.) And where do you have the 100 term list? In another table? (in which case we need the CREATE TABLE command for that too.) And what do you mean by a 'cell'?

Comment: P.S. Is this a one-off requirement? (Any suggested solution is likely to be highly affected by the answer to this question.) Overall you really need to provide a lot more information, and also to tell us what you have already tried & why it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @MandyShaw it's a Wordpress' postmeta table, the structure can be seen here -> https://imgur.com/oNpxror   The 100 terms list can be introduced manually directly in the query. This is a one-time task.

Comment: We can treat each of the 100 terms as a **substring** to search for them in that table column, where a cell content (the HTML + text) will be considered a **string** to search in.

Comment: There are some insights here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368621/mysql-search-in-longtext You clearly can't use full text searching. P.S. sorry to be dopey but I still don't understand what you mean by a 'cell', unless each LONGTEXT value is a cell?

Comment: If you are going to need to do the same processing 100 times, and depending on the number of rows, it might perhaps be worth getting the data into a more suitable format before you start. Maybe you could tokenise the strings somehow (assuming the terms can't overlap).

Comment: I've managed to achieve the desired result by writing a Python script for this. Thank you Mandy for your attempts in helping me.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted out.